# Tag assincrono com sinónimo

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tags-sinônimas

A tag [assincrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincrono) tem significado idêntico à de [assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincronismo).

Na minha perspectiva deve dar-se preferência à tag [assincrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincrono).
Se possível ela também deverá estar escrita correctamente [assíncrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ass%c3%adncrono).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feito. Todas as perguntas migradas para [assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincronismo), que possui [assincrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincrono) e [assíncrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ass%c3%adncrono) como sinônimos.